# web app debugging in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, variables

I have a Java Struts app in Eclipse and I'm looking for a way to see the values of request and session's variables (as the NetBeans display them), when running the app on Tomcat.

For some reason, the "Variable View" in debuggin mode is always empty, no way to fill it with variables I need to follow. Internal or external browser, no difference.

Please give me some hints, thx 
ONE DAY LATER:
Thank you for the answers. I will refine a little further my question, because still I'm not getting what I want. 
My reference is the table displayed in NetBeans (the "HTTP Monitor") were I can see the parameters and attributes associated with every Get or Post, ordered in "Request", "Session", "Context" tab.
In Eclipse the closer I can get now is to display in the "Expressions" view the variables I need. The problem is that there are not updated! For example, a "_client" variable linked with a drop-down select control will not reflect the changes.
Rather than a snapshot of the variable, I need a dynamic overview.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run Tomcat with JPDA enabled and [then you can attach the Netbeans debugger to it](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Developing#Q3).

Comment: That would be very convenient, thank you for the link.
I get a "Connection refused" message in NetBeans but I'm working on it. 
The downside is the performance of the system with Eclipse, Tomcat and NetBeans running in the same time! :¤!

Answer (score 0):

The variable view will be populated only when a thread is suspended.  Put a breakpoint on a line of interest, wait for the debugger to suspend the thread, and then examine the variables.

Comment: Thank you,
it helps me but still I would prefere a method to see the state of attributes and parameters without the need of breakpoints, "on the run" I would say.